# Loop through columns in a data.table and transform those columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `DT` with a column named `RF` and many columns with an underline `_`in it. I want to loop through all those columns with an 
underline and subtract the `RF` column from it. However, I'm stuck. It seems that everything on the RHS of the
`:=` operator in a `data.table` does not work with dynamic variables.

Here is my `DT` and the desired output (hardcoded):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(RF  = 1:10,
                 S_1 = 11:20,
                 S_2 = 21:30)
#Desired output
DT[ , S_1 := S_1 - RF]
DT[ , S_2 := S_2 - RF]
DT
      RF S_1 S_2
 [1,]  1  10  20
 [2,]  2  10  20
 [3,]  3  10  20
...
```

However, I want this to be more flexible, i.e. loop through every column with "_" in its name and subtract `RF`:

```
#1. try: Does not work; Interestingly, the i on the LHS of := is interpreted as the column i, but on the RHS of
#:= it is interpreted as 2 and 3, respectively
for (i in grep("_", names(DT))){
  DT[ , i:= i - 1, with=FALSE]
}
DT
          RF  S_1 S_2
 [1,]  1   1   2
 [2,]  2   1   2
 [3,]  3   1   2
...

#2. try: Work with parse and eval
for (i in grep("_", names(DT), value=TRUE)){
  DT[ , eval(parse(text=i)):= eval(parse(text=i)) - RF]
}
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'S_1' not found
```

Any hints how to do that would be great.

EDIT: As soon as I posted the question, I thought to myself: Why are you working with the `:=` operator in the first place, and sure enough, I just realized I don't have to. This does work and doesn't need a loop:

```
DT[, grep("_", names(DT)), with=FALSE] - DT[, RF]
```

Sorry for that. However, I leave the question open because I'm still interested on why my approach with the `:=` operator doesn't work. So maybe someone can help me there.

Comment: Plus one for finding the basic answer on your own -- AND letting us know about it.  :-)

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) I'd post this as an answer and accept it, and 2) Any benefits / cons to using `grep()` over `grepl()`?

Comment: @Chase OK, I will do that. However, I can't get the example to work with grepl, neither with `with=FALSE` nor without it. Thanks to both of you for your help! EDIT: I will accept the answer in two days, apparently I can't do it earlier.

Comment: @Chase I use `grepl` when I just need to slice out a section of the table, and regular `grep` when I need to use the indices for additional operations.

Comment: @Chase I also use `grepl` a lot for quick little inline `ifelse` statements.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question and reproducible example, and especially for leaving it up after you found a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were on the right track with your second attempt.  Here is an approach that uses `substitute` to build the expression that gets passed in as the `'j'` argument in `DT[ , j ]`.

```
for (i in grep("_", names(DT), value=TRUE)){
    e <- substitute(X := X - RF, list(X = as.symbol(i)))
    DT[ , eval(e)]
}
DT
#     RF S_1 S_2
# [1,]  1  10  20
# [2,]  2  10  20
# [3,]  3  10  20
# [4,]  4  10  20
# [5,]  5  10  20
```

---

You could also use an LHS expression rather than a symbol :

```
for (i in grep("_", names(DT), value=TRUE))
    DT[, (i) := get(i)-RF]
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh O'Brien, that does exactly what I was looking for (although I think that looping through is a bad idea in the first place, see my edit [obviously, that's a problem of my question, not your answer ;-)]). Anyways, now I will try to wrap my head around `substitute`, `eval`, `quote`, `deparse`, and so forth...I stumbled across them a couple of times and I think they are quite powerful in making a lot of stuff dynamic (as in your answer), but I still have problems understanding their full beauty...thanks again for showing me the way, though!

Comment: You're welcome, @Christoph_J. Also, a couple of thoughts. First I think in this case, looping _might_ be better, because it allows you to take advantage of data.table's modify-by-reference `:=` operator. (I may run some benchmarks later to check this, and will add results to my answer if I do). Second, to explore `substitute` et al., you might want to put a `browser()` call in `j`, like this:  `for(i in ......) { DT[ , browser()]}`. Then you can poke around 'inside of' DT, trying out different things (like `quote(i)`, `eval(quote(i)`, `as.symbol(eval(quote(i))`,  `eval(parse(text=i))` etc.)

Comment: Thanks again, @Josh O'Brien. I was aware of `debug()`, but never used `browser()` directly. That's a great hint!

Comment: For people how are struggling with `parse`, `eval`, etc. as well. Hadley Wickham has a really helpful article on that: [Controlling Evaluation](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation).

Comment: Also, of course, don't _start_ your investigations in a `DT[ ]` call, which has it's own well-chosen but still additional layer of scoping rules/behavior! (For info on that, see e.g. items 1.6 and 2.8 `vignette("datatable-faq")`).

Comment: This one could do with bringing up to date. Highlighted on datatable-help [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Update-columns-in-data-table-programmatically-tp4659283.html).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- In what way. Do you mean showing how to construct a single expression that performs multiple column modifications with a single `:=`? (If that's what you mean, I'm happy to do that, though it won't avoid the use of `as.symbol`, `substitute`, and `eval`...)

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- On a related topic, have you ever considered adding a `quote` argument like that in `do.call`? Unlike in `do.call`, its default would be `TRUE`, but when set to `FALSE`, the arguments would be evaluated in the calling environment before (subsequent) evaluation in the call to `[.data.table()`. (One might want separate `quote_i` and `quote_j` arguments, for extra control.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Just added quick edit what I was thinking. Nope - `quote` argument is new idea! Don't quite follow. Example would be great if poss please.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Let me think on it a bit, and I'll get back to you if it really is a good idea. Funny thing is the `get(i)` trick you just added in the edit accomplishes pretty much what I was thinking of. Nifty idea!

Answer (score 5):

A workaround which I unfortunately discovered after I posted the question is as follows:

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns('_')] - DT[, RF]
```

This also works in a more complicated setting in which there are additional columns you want to keep, but with some extra effort:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(RF  = 1:10,
                 S_1 = 11:20,
                 S_2 = 21:30,
                 addCol = rnorm(10)) #Column that should not be subtracted by RF, but still kept in DT

DT <- cbind(DT[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("_")] - DT[, RF], addCol = DT[, addCol])
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated to use `set()`+`..`; `set` is powerful (see edits for earlier attempt).

```
varnames <- grep("_", names(DT), value=TRUE)
set(DT, j = varnames, value = DT[, ..varnames] - DT[, RF])
```

Comment: Uhoh. Lines 3 and 5 use `[<-` and will copy the entire `DT`. Tasks like this are much easier with the `set()` function. There doesn't seem to be an answer here using `set` yet, do you want to have a go?

Comment: NP. Also DT[[varnames]] is faster and easier, instead of the with=FALSE.

Comment: Oops scratch that, varnames is a vector here isn't it.

Comment: Yes, `varnames` is a vector.