# How to do efficient vectorized update on multiple columns using data.tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following code using data.frames, and I'm wondering how to write this using data.tables, using the most efficient, most vectorized code?

data.frame code:

```
set.seed(1)
to <- cbind(data.frame(time=seq(1:5),bananas=sample(100,5),apples=sample(100,5)),setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(100,90,replace=T),nrow=5)),paste0(1:18)))
from <- cbind(data.frame(time=seq(1:5),blah=sample(100,5),foo=sample(100,5)),setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(100,90,replace=T),nrow=5)),paste0(1:18)))
from
to

rownames(to) <- to$time
to[as.character(from$time),paste0(1:18)] <- from[,paste0(1:18)]
to
```

Running this:

```
>     set.seed(1)
>     to <- cbind(data.frame(time=seq(1:5),bananas=sample(100,5),apples=sample(100,5)),setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(100,90,replace=T),nrow=5)),paste0(1:18)))
>     from <- cbind(data.frame(time=seq(1:5),blah=sample(100,5),foo=sample(100,5)),setNames(data.frame(matrix(sample(100,90,replace=T),nrow=5)),paste0(1:18)))
>     from
  time blah foo  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1    1   66  22 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2    2   35  13 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3    3   27  47 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4    4   97  90 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5    5   61  58 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
>     to
  time bananas apples  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1    1      27     90 21  50 94 39 49 67 83 79 48 10 92 26 34 90 44 21 24 80
2    2      37     94 18  72 22  2 60 80 65  3 87 32 30 48 84 87 72 72  6 46
3    3      57     65 69 100 66 39 50 11 79 48 44 52 46 77 35 39 40 13 65 42
4    4      89     62 39  39 13 87 19 73 56 74 25 67 34  9 34 78 33 25 88 82
5    5      20      6 77  78 27 35 83 42 53 70  8 41 66 88 48 97 76 15 78 61
> 
>     rownames(to) <- to$time
>     to[as.character(from$time),paste0(1:18)] <- from[,paste0(1:18)]
>     to
  time bananas apples  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1    1      27     90 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2    2      37     94 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3    3      57     65 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4    4      89     62 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5    5      20      6 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
```

Basically, we update columns `paste0(1:18)` of `to` from columns `paste0(1:18)` of `from`, matching up the `time`s.

`data.table`s apparently have some advantages, such as not needing head when printing them at the console, so I'm thinking about using them.

However I'd like not to have to write the `:=` expressions by hand, ie try to avoid:

```
to[from,`1`:=i.`1`,`2`:=i.`2`, ..]
```

I'd also prefer to use vectorized syntax if possible, rather than some kind of for loop, ie try to avoid something like:

```
for( i in 1:18 ) {
    to[from, sprintf("%d",i) := i.sprintf("%d",i)]
}
```

I read through the faq vignette, and the datatable-intro vignette, though I admit I probably haven't understood everything 100%.

I looked at [Loop through columns in a data.table and transform those columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374816/loop-through-columns-in-a-data-table-and-transform-those-columns) , but I can't say I understand it 100%, and it seems to say that I need to use a for loop?

There does seem to be some kind of a hint at the bottom of 8374816 that it might be possible to just use data frame syntax, adding `with=FALSE`?  But since the data.frame procedure is hacking on the row names, I'm not sure how well / if that will work, and I wonder to what extent that makes use of the efficiencies of data.table?

Comment: at least half of the difficulty you're running into is that you're using numbers for column names. If you instead prepend each column with a letter so they are "valid" column names you'll find this whole operation much easier.

Comment: @Justin, I'm ok with prefixing the columns with letters if that makes a solution possible that wouldn't be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.  The base construct you've shown :

```
to[as.character(from$time),paste0(1:18)] <- from[,paste0(1:18)]
```

works assuming row names can't be duplicated, or if they are then only the first is matched to. Here, the LHS of `<-` has the same number of rows as the RHS of `<-`.

`data.table` is different since routinely, multiple rows in `to` may match; the default for `mult` is `"all"`.  `data.table` also prefers long format to wide. So this question is kind of putting `data.table` through its paces for something it wasn't really designed for.  If you have any `NA` in those 18 columns (i.e. sparse), then a long format may be more appropriate.  If all 18 columns are the same type, then a `matrix` may be more appropriate.

That said, here are three `data.table` options for completeness.

**1. Using `:=` but without a for loop (multiple LHS and multiple RHS in LHS:=RHS)**

```
from = as.data.table(from)
to = as.data.table(to)
from
   time blah foo  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1   66  22 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2:    2   35  13 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3:    3   27  47 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4:    4   97  90 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5:    5   61  58 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
to
   time bananas apples  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1      27     90 21  50 94 39 49 67 83 79 48 10 92 26 34 90 44 21 24 80
2:    2      37     94 18  72 22  2 60 80 65  3 87 32 30 48 84 87 72 72  6 46
3:    3      57     65 69 100 66 39 50 11 79 48 44 52 46 77 35 39 40 13 65 42
4:    4      89     62 39  39 13 87 19 73 56 74 25 67 34  9 34 78 33 25 88 82
5:    5      20      6 77  78 27 35 83 42 53 70  8 41 66 88 48 97 76 15 78 61
setkey(to,time)
setkey(from,time)
to[from,paste0(1:18):=from[.GRP,paste0(1:18),with=FALSE]]
   time bananas apples  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1      27     90 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2:    2      37     94 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3:    3      57     65 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4:    4      89     62 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5:    5      20      6 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
```

**or**

```
to[from,paste0(1:18):=from[,paste0(1:18),with=FALSE],mult="first"]
   time bananas apples  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1      27     90 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2:    2      37     94 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3:    3      57     65 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4:    4      89     62 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5:    5      20      6 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
```

Note I'm using latest v1.8.3, which is needed for option 1 to work (`.GRP` has just been added, and the outer `with=FALSE` is no longer needed).

**2. Use one list column to store the length 18 vectors, rather than 18 columns**

```
to = data.table( time=seq(1:5),
                 bananas=sample(100,5),
                 apples=sample(100,5),  
                 v18=replicate(5,sample(100,18),simplify=FALSE))
from =  data.table( time=seq(1:5),
                    blah=sample(100,5),
                    foo=sample(100,5),
                    v18=replicate(5,sample(100,18),simplify=FALSE))
setkey(to,time)
setkey(from,time)

from
   time blah foo                 v18
1:    1   56  97   88,47,1,71,69,18,
2:    2   69  40   96,99,60,3,33,27,
3:    3   65  84 100,38,56,72,84,55,
4:    4   98  74 91,69,24,63,27,100,
5:    5   46  52    65,4,59,41,8,51,

to
   time bananas apples                 v18
1:    1      66     73 100,36,74,77,68,46,
2:    2      19     37   84,88,92,8,37,52,
3:    3      94     77   37,94,13,7,93,43,
4:    4      88      2  27,93,71,16,46,66,
5:    5      91     91   85,94,58,49,19,1,

to[from,v18:=i.v18]
to
   time bananas apples                 v18
1:    1      66     73   88,47,1,71,69,18,
2:    2      19     37   96,99,60,3,33,27,
3:    3      94     77 100,38,56,72,84,55,
4:    4      88      2 91,69,24,63,27,100,
5:    5      91     91    65,4,59,41,8,51,
```

If you are not used to list column printing, the trailing comma signifies that more items are in that vector. Just the first 6 are printed.

**3. Use `data.frame` syntax on the `data.table`**

```
to = as.data.table(to)
from = as.data.table(from)
setkey(to,time)
setkey(from,time)

from
   time blah foo  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1   66  22 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2:    2   35  13 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3:    3   27  47 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4:    4   97  90 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5:    5   61  58 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79

to
   time bananas apples  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1      27     90 21  50 94 39 49 67 83 79 48 10 92 26 34 90 44 21 24 80
2:    2      37     94 18  72 22  2 60 80 65  3 87 32 30 48 84 87 72 72  6 46
3:    3      57     65 69 100 66 39 50 11 79 48 44 52 46 77 35 39 40 13 65 42
4:    4      89     62 39  39 13 87 19 73 56 74 25 67 34  9 34 78 33 25 88 82
5:    5      20      6 77  78 27 35 83 42 53 70  8 41 66 88 48 97 76 15 78 61

to[from, paste0(1:18)] <- from[,paste0(1:18),with=FALSE]
to
   time bananas apples  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1:    1      27     90 98  2 100 46 58 60 69 46 62 19 29 42 64 90 30 19 72 60
2:    2      37     94 74 72  50 52  8 57 61 18 56 53 90  7 85 65 20 76 39 12
3:    3      57     65 36 11  49 21  4 53 24 75 33  8 45 34 86 75 89 73 11 85
4:    4      89     62 44 45  18 23 65 99 26 11 46 28 78 73 40 61 51 95 93 32
5:    5      20      6 15 65  76 60 93 51 73 87 51 22 89 34 39 91 88 55 29 79
```

So the LHS of `<-` can use `data.table` keyed join syntax; i.e. `to[from]`. It's just that this method (currently in R) will copy the *entire* `to` dataset.  That's what `:=` was introduced to avoid by providing update by reference. Also, if each row in `from` matches to multiple rows in `to` then the RHS of `<-` would need to expanded to line up (by you the user), otherwise the RHS would be recycled to fill up the LHS. That's one reason why, in `data.table`, we like `:=` being inside `j`, all inside `[...]`.